# Programmatically Get App-Level Token for Slack App with Socketmode Enabled

Tags: slack, slack-api

I created a Slack App with Socketmode enabled. I  am trying to distribute this app and I need to generate App-Level token after application is installed to workspace. Currently, I am able to use Slack Oauth flow to get bot access token, but I couldn't find how to get app-level token for each installation. App-level token is a must have parameter for socketmode. Do you know,

- If I can get it from Oauth response?
- I can generate app level token programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The app-level token in Slack platform represents your app and your app alone. It isn't attached to a specific workspace installation.

When you connect to socket mode using an app-level token, the perspective on the stream is that of all possible workspaces your app is installed in.

You'll still need workspace-level tokens to use the Web API on behalf of your app-workspace or app-workspace-user relationship, often in response to events you receive.

But the app token is really an that lives outside of OAuth and workspaces.

Comment: Does the app-level token require any token rotation?

Comment: App-level tokens can be rotated manually but there are no explicit requirements to implement token rotation mandated.